# Devexpress annotations

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I am trying to make use of devexpress annotations to achieve the following chart. I need the values in line with each other:

[image]

However when I try it using annotations at my end I got this:

[image]

This is my code of annotations:

```
With dp.Annotations(0)    
    .BackColor = Color.Transparent
    .Border.Visible = False
    .AnchorPoint = New SeriesPointAnchorPoint(dp)
    .ShapePosition = New RelativePosition(180, -200)
    .Width = 20
    .Height = 30
End With
```

I need some way to put the annoatations in line with each other.